# Returning error level to an external file when working on sqlcmd

Tags: vb.net, sqlcmd

I want to obtain the errorlevel on an external file when execution of sql statements is done in cmd.exe so that I can proceed with my further coding.

I have used ECHO command and error level is displayed on the prompt,but i want to obtain it on an external file
My code is like this;

```
  Dim strCmdText As String
        strCmdText = "/C sqlcmd -S " & Server & " -d " & Databasename & " -i " & FileName & " -o " & ResultFile & " -V "
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText)
```

here output is returned in Resultfile,likewise i want to return the errorlevel.

Comment: How about some logging framework (log4net, NLog etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the echo command prompts it for you why not use

```
@echo message> c:\test.txt
```

Also u can use

```
if errorlevel 1 goto function

:Function
@echo message> c:\test.txt
```

I think this is what you want?
Instead of output maybe use the echo command to write to the file instead?

Answer (score 0):

Using vb.net, Use try catch when running "command.ExecuteNonQuery()" and save the error to txt. Is there a good reason for using cmd?

Like so..

```
Try
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch (Ex As Exception)
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter 
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\test.txt", True)
    file.WriteLine(ex.message) 
    file.Close()
End try
```

Take a look at this also found in a thread if you still want to use RedirectStandardOutput:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO

Private CurrentProcessID As Integer = -1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
StartProcess("C:\Windows\System32\tracert.exe", "stackoverflow.com")
End Sub

Private Sub StartProcess(FileName As String, Arguments As String)

Dim MyStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo() With {
    .FileName = FileName,
    .Arguments = Arguments,
    .WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName),
    .RedirectStandardError = True,
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True,
    .UseShellExecute = False,
    .CreateNoWindow = True
}

Dim MyProcess As Process = New Process() With {
    .StartInfo = MyStartInfo,
    .EnableRaisingEvents = True,
    .SynchronizingObject = Me
}

MyProcess.Start()
MyProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()
MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()

CurrentProcessID = MyProcess.Id

AddHandler MyProcess.OutputDataReceived,
    Sub(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        If e.Data IsNot Nothing Then
            BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(
            Sub()
                RichTextBox1.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine)
                RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
            End Sub))
        End If
    End Sub

AddHandler MyProcess.ErrorDataReceived,
    Sub(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        If e.Data IsNot Nothing Then
            BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(
            Sub()
                RichTextBox1.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine)
                RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
            End Sub))
        End If
    End Sub

AddHandler MyProcess.Exited,
    Sub(source As Object, ev As EventArgs)
        MyProcess.Close()
        If MyProcess IsNot Nothing Then
            MyProcess.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
End Sub
```